# Create RAM disk on the VM, or on the host?

Tags: debian, virtual-machine, windows-server-2012, ramdisk

I am interacting programatically between two programs (Matlab, and ISpice),
where one program writes a file to disk then the other reads it and writes another file to disk, which is read by the first.
This appears to be the standard way people programmatically interact with the second program (ISpice).

Since now writing to disk is a bottleneck in my program (I haven't yet tested this but assuming it is), then I could use a RAM disk to speed it up.
The disk would need to be about 64Mb. The files stored in it are just temporary for interchange of data.
RAM disk seems to be the closest thing I can get to shared memory between the applications.

The programs are running on a Window Server 2012 VM,
inside a KVM host, running Debian (and using Proxmox for management).

There is plenty of RAM in VM host, and I can easily throw a bit more RAM into the VM itself.

I see two ways to go about creating the RAM disk.

- I could create it in windows (I don't think it can be done natively in windows, but there are 3rd party tools.)
- I could create is in the linux VM host, and then mount it in windows

What are the Pros and Cons of each approach?

Comment: Why don't you not verify this is actually your bottkneck, and if it is, try both approaches to see which one is better for YOU.

Comment: Because I want to benefit from the experience of others. Why rediscover the best way to do a thing?